# How might I clear out my pool’s filter system pump of debris?

Tags: outdoor, pool, filter, blockage

I found the pool's filter cup dislodged and floating around the inlet tube, letting debris run straight into the pump system. Since then the outflow rate has been reduced severely. How may I be able to fix this?

Comment: Probably best to consider the entire filtration system compromised (since you don't know how long the filter has been missing), and plan on giving the whole thing a good servicing. Assume there are leaves, twigs, etc. _everywhere_.

Answer (score 1):

That's sounds like the strainer,  the actual filter is probably clogged now.  follow the procedure for cleaning or replacing the filter.